# onItemClick() doesn't work with a Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I would like to create a list of androidPlot, and when I click on one item i would like to start another activity.
Now the List of Plot is done, but the listener doesn'work.

I try to do this:

```
 mPlotList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
          }    
        }
```

what is the problem?
Thank you to all!

Comment: [`onItemClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener))

Answer (score 0):

you should set this:

```
mPlotList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // position means item that clicked
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

mPlotList.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
          {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // position means item that clicked
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```